# Selecting and assigning text to subelement of a repeater in editor-x

Tags: velo

I have a repeater that shows prices and products and I want to format the price to have currency symbols next to it.

I didn't find any simple solution so I try to do it using Velo.

Looking at the documentation I see I need to select the repeater using `$w`, and then selecting the subelement using the `$item`.

Sadly it doesn't work, applying the same code on elements in the global scope works fine.

Any ideas?

```
$w('#repeater1').onItemReady(($item, itemData, index) => {
    let repeatedElement = $item("#price20");
    repeatedElement.text = itemData.price.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })
    console.log(itemData.price)
    console.log(repeatedElement.text)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

1. I had to make sure the dataset is on ready first.
2. convert the string to a number before formatting.

```
$w('#dataset3').onReady(() => {
            $w('#repeater1').forEachItem(($w, itemData, index) => {
        `enter code here`        console.log(itemData.price)
                $w('#price20').text = (+itemData.price).toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency'`enter code here`, currency: 'EUR' })
    
            });
        });
```